# Cocoa Objective-C: use c++ objects as NSDictionary keys?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa

I have a c++ framework that I am using alongside my Objective-C (Cocoa) code. I currently implement wrapper classes to pass my c++ objects around the obj-C code.

The c++ objects are stored as a hierarchy, and, I've recently realized that I need to have a one-to-one correspondence between the obj-C objects and the c++ objects, as I'm using these as NSOutlineView items, which a) need to be obj-c objects, and b) need to be exact (i.e., I need to give the same obj-c object every time for the corresponding c++ object).

I'm a bit stuck for the best (i.e., easiest) way to do this. I'd ideally have something like an NSDictionary, where I input the c++ object as a key, and get back the corresponding obj-c object. Is there any way to convert a c++ object to a **unique** key, so that I could use NSDictionary in this manner? Or is there any other practical way to write a function to achieve a similar purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ofcourse you can convert any class object into [hash](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) values. The code below demonstrates how to specialize std::hash for a user defined type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

struct S
{
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
};

namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<S>
    {
        typedef S argument_type;
        typedef std::size_t result_type;

        result_type operator()(argument_type const& s) const
        {
            result_type const h1 ( std::hash<std::string>()(s.first_name) );
            result_type const h2 ( std::hash<std::string>()(s.last_name) );
            return h1 ^ (h2 << 1);
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    S s;
    s.first_name = "Bender";
    s.last_name =  "Rodriguez";
    std::hash<S> hash_fn;

    std::cout << "hash(s) = " << hash_fn(s) << "\n";
}
```

with an example output:

hash(s) = 32902390710

which is a pretty high number, which makes it highly unlikely to have collisions for relativelly small number of objects.

with the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).